# MySQLi issue: connecting but query not working

Tags: php, mysqli

so i'm not sure what the issue is but i'm pretty basic with mysql and i'm still learning. However I have been searching on the internet for about two hours now and I cant figure out what i've done wrong.

```
<?php
$id = 0;
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbname, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed" . $conn->connect_error);
}
$user_qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id";

$result = $conn->query($user_qry);
echo("<pre>");
print_r($result);
$conn->close();
?>
```

I am not receiving any connection error, but i'm

Comment: $conn = new mysqli($servername, **$dbname**, $password);

Comment: It's also the username

Comment: `new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);`

Comment: @Mihai combined with Shaeldon's answer that worked. Thanks. But how was I able to connect successfully to the database without giving the database name?

Comment: I coudnt tell you,but common sense tells you that you coudn`t connect without a username.Maybe you connected with anonymous user,it`s a mysql thing eveb for wrong usernames but you cant do anything with that user.

Comment: @Mihai godaddy's rules, the first user is always named after the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the result after executing the query:

```
     $result = $conn->query($user_qry);
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            print_r($row);
     }
```

Regarding comment, stolen from another Stack Overflow post:

```
$result = $conn->query($user_qry)
if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->database->errno}] {$this->database->error}");
}
```

Comment: Tried that and getting an error: 
 Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: @SQLDummy then your query fails, see edit on how to fetch the error

Comment: I tried your answer with Mihai (check in the comments) all working now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your connection, make sure you have selected a database name

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$conn->select_db('test');
```

And one more thing, to see what is the error you should enable display_errors = On in php.ini